# A word for "I am here!"

Tags: single-word-requests

I will try to explain it as much as I can, so please bear with me. I am looking for a word which means/implies "I am here" but not for humans, please consider the sentence below:

> Using "SomeCompany.com" instead of "somecompany.com" looks much better
>   as capitals letters make your company name *say "I am here"* within the given domain.

What I am thinking is "stand out" as a possible word. But getting more ideas from experts is always the best.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a clue what you mean. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Rather than trying to find another word meaning "I am here", you can reword your phrase to say "....as capital letters emphasize on your company's presence within the given domain."

Comment: @Billy: Please consider the Bill's sentence. It seems he understand s what I meant.

Comment: @Braveyard: Okay, I now understand that you are trying to replace the phrase 'say "I am here"' in your quotation. But I can't really guess at what sort of thing you're trying to replace it by. I don't know what it means for a company name to *say "I am here"*. That doesn't mean anything in my mind, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Billy: What do you think about "stand out"? Could it be a appropriate choice in this case?

Comment: @Braveyard: I have no idea what the phrase in your question is supposed to mean! If you can give me some idea of what 'say "I am here"' means, I can try to tell you whether "stand out" is an appropriate substitute for it.

Comment: @Billy: Don't worry mate!  I am a computer nerd, and therefore speak Geek!  I also happen to be Greek.... ;-)

Comment: @Billy: "I am here" means like it wants to grab attention of people  like a shout "I am here! Check me out!"

Comment: Voici! fill, fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that:

"capital letters give your company name extra visibility", or

"capital letters draw attention to your company name", or

"capital letters make your company name more eye-catching", or

"capital letters make your company name catch the eye".

Comment: I think that answer it pretty enough for me. Thanks Hellion, as always.

Comment: I have frequently heard our graphics people say things like “this will make the company name really pop”.